# Passing select as param to function not working

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to use recursion and pass the select as param to the function

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_film_count(a varchar[], v varchar[])
RETURNS TABLE(id varchar, in_node varchar, out_node varchar, costs decimal, path varchar[], node_list varchar[], visted_list varchar[], cycle Boolean)
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS '
DECLARE
    list_of_out_nodes varchar[];
BEGIN
            RETURN QUERY  
                WITH my_node_with(id, in_node, out_node, costs, path, node_list, visted_list, cycle) AS (
                SELECT edg.id, edg.in_node, edg.out_node, edg.costs, ARRAY[edg.id], 
                ARRAY[edg.in_node,edg.out_node], v || ARRAY[edg.in_node], edg.in_node = ANY(v) 
                FROM edges edg where edg.in_node = Any(a) and edg.in_node != ANY(v)
                UNION ALL
                SELECT edg1.id, edg1.in_node, edg1.out_node, edg1.costs, ARRAY[edg1.id], 
                ARRAY[edg1.in_node,edg1.out_node], v || ARRAY[edg1.in_node], edg1.in_node = ANY(v) 
                FROM edges edg1 where edg1.out_node = ANY(SELECT  edg2.in_node FROM edges edg2 where edg2.in_node = edg1.out_node and edg2.out_node != ANY(v) )
                
                )
                SELECT r.id,r.out_node,r.in_node, r.costs, r.path, r.node_list, r.visted_list, r.cycle from my_node_with r;
         

END; ';
select * from get_film_count(ARRAY['a'], ARRAY['']);
```

The above is the code which is working which is a simplified version for debugging. The following is the code I am trying to get working

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_film_count(a varchar[], v varchar[])
RETURNS TABLE(id varchar, in_node varchar, out_node varchar, costs decimal, path varchar[], node_list varchar[], visted_list varchar[], cycle Boolean)
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS '
DECLARE
    list_of_out_nodes varchar[];
BEGIN
            RETURN QUERY  
                WITH my_node_with(id, in_node, out_node, costs, path, node_list, visted_list, cycle) AS (
                SELECT edg.id, edg.in_node, edg.out_node, edg.costs, ARRAY[edg.id], 
                ARRAY[edg.in_node,edg.out_node], v || ARRAY[edg.in_node], edg.in_node = ANY(v) 
                FROM edges edg where edg.in_node = Any(a) and edg.in_node != ANY(v)
                        UNION ALL
                                select * from get_film_count((SELECT edg2.in_node FROM edges edg2 where edg2.in_node = edg.out_node and edg2.out_node != ANY(v)), (v || ARRAY[edg.in_node]))                        
                )
                SELECT r.id,r.out_node,r.in_node, r.costs, r.path, r.node_list, r.visted_list, r.cycle from my_node_with r;
         

END; ';
select * from get_film_count(ARRAY['a'], ARRAY['']);
```

but I get

```
[Code: 0, SQL State: 42P01]  ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "edg"
  Where: PL/pgSQL function get_film_count(character varying[],character varying[]) line 5 at RETURN QUERY
```

Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: Are you doing anything wrong? Yes.  Each component (select) in a `union/union all` query must actually be independent, with the restriction that they return the same number of items and  of comparable data types. In this case you define the alias `edg` for table `edges` in the first select (before union clause) then attempt to use it again in the second select (after union clause). However the alias `edg` is not defined in the second select and therefore not usable.